# Delta time not working properly with GLFW

Tags: c++, time, glfw

In a while loop I am calling an update function of an object:

```
void ParticleEmitter::update(float deltaTime) {
    time += deltaTime;

    if (time >= delay) {
        addParticle();
        time = 0;
    }
}
```

`time` variable is set to 0 by default. It's basically elapsed time.
`delay` is 0.01. Meaning that after each 0.01 second, it should do whatever is in the `if` statement.

This seems frame rate-independent. But it is not. When I cap the FPS to 60 or turn on VSync, less particles seem to be added.

The delta time is being calculated properly, I have tested it. But I am confused to why this code isn't frame rate-independent.

Comment: Things to consider:  `deltaTime` greater than `delay`.  If capping the frame rate, is the idle time spent waiting for the interval to elapse factored into `deltaTime`?

Comment: Yes, in fact any movement that I do for example ```position += velocity * deltaTime```, that seems to give me the same speed no matter the frame rate, but when dealing with this kind of stuff, like adding particles once every 0.01 seconds, it gives me problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you are probaly not factoring in the remaining time in `deltaTime`.

For example imagine that you have `deltaTime` = 0.05 or `deltaTime` = 0.1 as you are only checking that it is greater or equal then, it will only generate one particle each time that update is called. So if deltaTime is smaller (framerate higher) then update will be called more often than if deltaTime is bigger.

The solution is to apply a function like so which generates a number of particles based in the timeElapsed (extracted from my own particle generator)

```
void particleSystem::generateParticles(float timeStep)
{
    float particlesToCreate = particlesPerSecond * timeStep;
    unsigned int count = static_cast <unsigned int> (particlesToCreate);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        emitParticle();
    }
}
```

With `particlesPerSecond` being a configurable parameter in the `particleSystem`
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response :) That is a nice approach. Another note here, that my frame rate is never fixed, it is constantly changing (if capped, very minute changes), even if the frame rate is capped.

Comment: @ReluctantProgrammer No worries! If you want a good tutorial on particles, checkout ThinMatrix on youtube hes pretty good explaining this. Yeah i used to do variable timestep before, but i got enlighted into using fixed time step :D. This answer works for both cases.

Comment: Yep, I love ThinMatrix, he solved most of my worries. Same for TheChernoProject. Thanks a lot anyways :D

Comment: @ReluctantProgrammer hahaha same here. I will check out TheChernoProject too. Glad it helped! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Comment: @ReluctantProgrammer Hahaha no worries, i am pretty new myself. Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

It's not framerate-independent.

For simplicity, let's assume that `deltaTime` is fixed.

If it is 0.1, you will add one particle every 0.1 seconds, because 0.1 > 0.01.
If it is 0.01, you will add one particle every 0.01 seconds.
If it is 1/60 (60 FPS), you will add one particle every 1/60 (~0.01667) seconds, because 1/60 is larger than 0.01.
If it is 1/120, you will also add one particle every 1/60 seconds, because 1/120 is smaller than 0.01 and 2 * 1/120 is larger than 0.01.

If you want a fixed number of particles per time, you need to add several if the delta is large.

Something like

```
while (time >= delay)
{
    addParticle();
    time -= delay;
}
```

You also don't want to set `time` to 0, but save the "spill time"  for the next update.

There is a drawback with this approach; adding more particles takes time so the next update may come later. This can cause a long ripple effect.
If that happens, you will need a more sophisticated approach.